# Reading property file in Java

Tags: java, filereader

My code is not able to read the property file. Can anyone help here? It prints unable to find the file.

```
BufferedReader br = null;
String strLine = "";
try {
    br = new BufferedReader( new FileReader("C:/common-test/common-test/translationtest/messages_ja.property"));
    while( (strLine = br.readLine()) != null){
        System.out.println(strLine);
    }
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    System.err.println("Unable to find the file: fileName");
} catch (IOException e) {
    System.err.println("Unable to read the file: fileName");
}
```

Comment: change `/` to `\\` and also escape them

Comment: I strongly recommend printing the actual Exception instead of your own custom output. That will give you far more information (like why it's not working).

Comment: What exception do you get? Please use this code `catch(IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }` and show us the error message

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this `\\`:

```
 "C:\\common-test\\common-test\\translationtest\\messages_ja.property"
```

Are you sure to use `.property` or `.properties`.